# FileNotFoundException for apk file with HttpURLConnection in Android

Tags: java, android

```
            URL url = new URL(arg0[1]);
            HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            c.setRequestMethod("GET");
            c.setDoOutput(true);
            c.connect();

            String PATH = "/mnt/sdcard/Android/";
            File file = new File(PATH);
            file.mkdirs();
            File outputFile = new File(file, "myGame.apk");
            if(outputFile.exists()){
                outputFile.delete();
            }
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

            InputStream is = c.getInputStream();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len1 = 0;
            while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
            }
            fos.close();
            is.close();

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File("mnt/sdcard/Android/myGame.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(intent);
```

I want to do auto-update app function and it will download the apk file and install it. However when I download through Java and exception caught: `java.io.FileNotFoundException http://192.168.2.143/myGame.apk`, where url[0]="http://192.168.2.143/myGame.apk", I use browser in my device to open `http://192.168.2.143/myGame.apk`, the apk can be downloaded and inside sdcard/Download/ folder. I have INTERNET permission in my manifest. Any idea?

Comment: are you testing on the emulator ?

Comment: Try after removing c.setDoOutput(true)

Comment: I run on my device not emulator

Comment: Removing `c.setDoOutput(true)` works. Thanks

Comment: It doesn't show the error, However, it doesn't download anything. @AkariKamigishi

Answer (score 1):

As Brijesh Thakur said

Remove `c.setDoOutput(true)`